# Retrieving authenticated user after receiving SAML from Microsoft Intra ID (AAD° as identity Provider

Tags: rest, authentication, spring-security, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am facing an issue retrieving the authenticated user after receiving SAML from Microsoft Intra ID as the Identity Provider (IdP). The Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal object is always **null**.

```
  @RequestMapping("/init")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {
        System.out.println(principal.getAttributes());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("success");

    }
```

**- spring boot version**: 3.2.2
**- package of Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal:**org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication

I have tried the following:
Configuring Spring Security SAML with Intra ID as IdP.
Successfully receiving the SAML response after login.
Parsing the SAML response and extracting the user attributes.
However, the Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal object is still null. I am not sure what I am missing.